# 64-bit and 32-bit unmanaged dlls on the same system - best practices?

Tags: windows, dll, 32bit-64bit

I have a shared dll which is built in 32 bit and 64 bit. Both builds use the same name, foo.dll. How can I install both foo.dlls on the system so that my 32 bit and 64 bit apps find the correct dlls in their path.

Windows itself uses SysWOW64 (for 32-bit dlls) and System32 (for 64-bit dlls). I would like to avoid deploying to these folders. What is the accepted way (if any) to have a dll in both bitnesses coexist on the same box and be found by the appropriate applications that are linked to them?

Comment: Isn't SysWOW64 for 64bit dlls?

Comment: @Bali C No. SysWow64 is for 32 images and system32 is for 64 bit images. There is actually some logic behind that!

Comment: Just don't share DLLs.  There is no simple way to do this anymore left in Windows.  And there's very little point in persisting DLL Hell.  Ship your 64-bit build of the DLL with a 64-bit installer for a 64-bit program.  Put it in the same folder as the EXE.

Comment: @Hans What if you are shipping a DLL that is meant to be used as a library by other apps. I do exactly that. How are those apps meant to find it?

Comment: @David - finding a DLL in the same folder as the EXE is never a problem, Windows looks there first.  You probably didn't mean that :)  The idea of having one DLL used by multiple EXEs is dead and buried.  "Dll hell lies here" on the tombstone.  Unless these EXEs are all stored in the same folder and deployed there at the same time.

Comment: @Hans No I understand all that. I ship a DLL that doesn't have a EXE on top. My clients supply that. Commonly the exe is python.exe. I don't want my DLL in the python install directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't deploy to a folder that is subject to file redirection (i.e. system32) then you pretty much need to give the DLLs different names. The reason for this is that the DLL search path is shared between 32 and 64 bit processes and if you are relying on the search path to locate the DLL, that forces you to use different names.

Note that I am ruling out any solutions that rely on SxS versioning. Attempting to go down that route leads to all sorts of complications and headaches for anyone attempting to use your DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate how you were installing your binaries or how they were getting loaded or installed, but I surmise that the solution will involve having separate installation directories for 32-bit vs. 64-bit installs.

Traditionally, 32-bit apps installed on 64-bit machines typically get installed into a subfolder of "c:\program files(x86)" instead of "c:\program files".  I'm assuming 32-bit apps and setups (including MSIs) that call GetSpecialFolder, will get redirected to the c:\program files(x86) directory.

You don't have to worry about 64-bit binaries getting installed on 32-bit OS.  Just block that from happening in setup, since those binaries won't load anyway.

Comment: Program Files folder is not subject to the file redirector. When you link against a library you need to consider the library search path rather than GetSpecialFolder, CSIDL etc. This advice is reasonable for installation time, but not relevant to runtime DLL loading, i.e. LoadLibrary.